# Лексические нормы, исправить лексические ошибки и обосновать

Tags: лексика

1. в развитии сюжета нас ожидает немало неожиданностей и интересных сюрпризов
2. трибуна была представлена гостям
3. мы помчались туда очертив голову
4. этот метод позволит повысить эффективность труда
5. в кашпо растёт растение плющ
6. этот человек был полный невежа в искусстве

Возможны варианты:
1)В развитии сюжета нас ожидает немало неожиданных  интересных сюрпризов,так как неожиданности и сюрпризы имеют общее лексическое значение?
2).трибуна была предоставлена гостям,так как представить можно кому-то, представить гостя и тд
3.)
4)этот метод повысит эффективность труда,так как два глагола
5). В кашпо растёт плющ,так как растёт и растение однокоренные слова
6)Этот человек был полным невеждой в искусстве

Исправьте меня,если неправильно.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что это д/з.

Comment: Это не д/з а задание из контрольной работы первого курса нефтяного техникума заочного отделения

Comment: Согласна, я тоже так думаю, Артём.

Comment: Трудно помочь??

Comment: Не трудно, просто пишите от себя хоть что-то, а не только указания с глаголами в инфинитиве.

Comment: Я и написала...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. В развитии сюжета нас ждет  много неожиданного и интересного.
2. Трибуна была предоставлена гостям.
3. Мы помчались туда очертя голову.
4. Применение этого  метода позволит повысить эффективность труда.
5. В кашпо растёт  плющ.
6. Этот человек был полным невеждой в искусстве.